# Change in Correlation after Imputation of Missing Outcome Data for Machine Learning Prediction Task

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I am attempting to generate a predictive model for a continuous outcome using machine learning models. However, some observations in the original dataset have missing outcome data (and missing predictor values). I had been using mice to impute the missing outcome data, first generating the imputation scheme on the training data and re-using it on the test data. After the models performed worse than expected, I noticed that after imputing the data, the correlation between some of the most important predictors has decreased as compared to what was observed in the original data. In short, there is one main predictor that has a correlation of ~0.92 with the outcome in the complete cases analysis in the full dataset (train + test), but this correlation drops to the range of 0.4 to 0.6 in the imputed test data. In the training data, the decrease in correlation is more modest, with the correlation generally remaining around 0.8.

My models were not generalizing well to the test data, and I suspect this may have been due to the decrease in correlation between the variables. Is this an expected result, or does it suggest that something is incorrect with the imputation model being used, such as assumptions being violated? I'm happy to provide more information if necessary - just a bit confused as to why the correlation has changed so dramatically!

EDIT: One comment about the data that may be important - many of the features are highly correlated with one another, so not sure if this will also cause problems with mice.

Comment: When you say the performance got worse, how was it measured before? Only on the subset of data without missing values?

Comment: Yes, I also used a complete case analysis and the R^2 comparing the elastic net model predictions to actual outcome data was 0.94 in test data for complete case, but 0.2 in the test data for analysis using multiple imputation. The MAE and RMSE also more than doubled. I haven't checked with my other models yet since this surprised me so much, I wanted to check my process first.

Comment: You cannot really compare a complete case analysis with an analysis with imputation, because that's based on different data.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm still a bit surprised/confused that the correlation between the features and outcomes has decreased so much in the test data, though, as I would have expected this correlation to remain strong based on the real-world relationship between these variables. Is there a general reason why the correlation would decrease after imputation, or will it take much more detailed investigation of the data to determine what is happening?

Comment: One possibility is that one cannot impute the missing data with a lot of certainty (i.e. it will end up being pretty uncertain), in that case relationships will be less strong than they would be if we had observed the missing data.